# Use € as currency symbol in NumeralTickFormatter from bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews, bokehjs

I would like to use the € symbol instead of $ to format my numbers in a bokeh plot that is created by holoviews (hv.Bars).

```
formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format=f"{€ 0.00 a)")
```

Unfortunately, this does only yield a formatted number but not the Euro symbol

Also, the work-around as mentioned here

[How to format bokeh xaxis ticks with currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697773/how-to-format-bokeh-xaxis-ticks-with-currency)

with

```
formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format=f'€ 0.00 a')
```

does not work.

I actually think that bokeh should adapt to this and provide the possibility to add anything as symbol.

Comment: Bokeh just passes the format string you give to a `PrintfTickFormatter` to the `sprintf-js` library, and that is not a valid format string for that formatter.

Comment: In any case, if you think that something should be part of the library, the appropriate step to take is to [make a GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) that describes your need in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using `FuncTickFormatter` and a bit of TypeScript code.

```
from bokeh.models import FuncTickFormatter
p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code='''Edit some typescript here.''')
```

**Minimal Example**
If your goal is to edit the x-axis for values between 0 and 1e7 this should work. This will select no unit for values smaller than 1000,  `k` for values between 1000 and 1e6, and `m` for bigger values.

```
p = figure(width=400, height=400, title=None, toolbar_location="below")
x = [xx*1e6 for xx in range(1,6)]
y = [2, 5, 8, 2, 7]
p.circle(x, y, size=10)

js = """
if (tick < 1e3){
    var unit = ""
    var num =  (tick).toFixed(2)
}
else if (tick < 1e6){
    var unit = "k"
    var num =  (tick/1e3).toFixed(2)
}
else{
    var unit = "m"
    var num =  (tick/1e6).toFixed(2)
}
return `€ ${num} ${unit}`
"""

p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code=js)
show(p)
```

**Output**

[image: using FuncTickFormatter]

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, this code is not able to automatically determine if the number should be displayed in 1k / 1m / .. (The intention behind the 'a' format )

Comment: Well, you adapt the typescript code and making some if cases.

Comment: Well, I upvote since it does what I asked for but is not a clean solution since my numbers can get really big and I don't appreciate x-elif cases. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I edited my solution. I think it is not to hard to make some changes for your case.

Answer (score 2):

`NumeralTickFormatter` and `PrintfTickFormatter` are different, and utilize entirely different formatting strings. If you want to use `PrintfTickFormatter`, you need to give it a valid "printf" format string:

```
PrintfTickFormatter(format='€ %0.2f')
```

[image]

The valid printf formats are all described [in the documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html?highlight=printftickformatter#bokeh.models.formatters.PrintfTickFormatter)